# cant see model from template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am unable to set model to template,
I am trying to do like this:
from my view:

```
 var tmpl = _.template($('#table_template').html() );
        view.$el.html(tmpl(listSongs));
```

and my template:

```
   </div><!-- /.row -->
    <div class="list-group">
        <div  id="table_template">
            <%= listSongs.nextLink %>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="pager">
                <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

but the issue that when I see just <%= listSongs.nextLink %>

Comment: Maybe just `<%= nextLink %>` instead of `<%= listSongs.nextLink %>` ? And yes, `listSongs` in `view.$el.html(tmpl(listSongs))` need to be an object which has the key 'nextLink'.

Comment: tryed but it strange i just see my html page just as text like :  <%= listSongs.nextLink %> it disent set any value just like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the template inside your HTML, so its contents are treated as a part of the page and the text is shown.

The solution is to put the template inside a `<script>` tag of a custom type:

```
<script id="table_template" type="text/template">
    <div>
        <%= listSongs.nextLink %>
    </div>
</script>
```

This way, the browser ignores the template and does not treat it as a part of the page.

This is based on [an example](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Backbone%2C-The-Primer#rendering-with-templates) from Backbone, The Primer.